# Compare two population means at different time point

Tags: mean, population, z-test

I am trying to determine the change in the size of a population during a 20 year period using two scenarios. I run the model for each scenario 100 times under different random seeds and then take the average value as shown in the figure below. I think the z-test is the most appropriate to compare the two means, but in my case I need to compare the mean at different time step. I thought to run the z-test for each point in time, but I am not sure if this acceptable or not.

[image]